# Mysql - как можно вернуть 0 в count, если нет совпадений?

Tags: mysql

Можно ли получить 0, если нет совпадений?

```
SELECT id, description,start_date, end_date, count(student_of_course.student_id)
as COUNT FROM course
INNER JOIN student_of_course ON course.id= student_of_course.course_id WHERE start_date >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: а сейчас что выдаёт?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сейчас показывает только, если есть в таблице соответствующие `student_of_course ON course.id= student_of_course.course_id` и выдает кол-во `student_of_course.student_id`

Comment: значит дело не в count?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский count правильно работает, но мне надо чтоб выводило 0, если нет совпадений, собственно вопрос, можно ли это сделать с помощью count?

Comment: Если хотите без совпадений, то почему делаете `INNER JOIN`, а не `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon так это ничего не меняет, т.к. считает по записям в таблице, а если их нет, то соответственно не считает ибо их нет, я хочу, если нет записей - то чтоб было 0 в колонке count, но я не знаю как этого добиться

Comment: Что значит не меняет? Меняет. Если inner join, то курсов без студентов не выведет. А если left join, то выведет курсы без студентов. И если я не ошибаюсь, то при student_id == null, count выдаст 0. Но во всяком случае, если student_id == null, то студента нет на курсе

Comment: @ArchDemon в таблице хранится связка course_id + student_id, то есть не может быть пустой course_id + null или наоборот. Допустим, если есть курс, но на нем нет еще студентов, то записи в таблице нет (student_of_course), и это значит что count = 0 . Извиняюсь, я возможно неправ ибо очень мало практики с mysql

Comment: Да знаю я что у вас там хранится. Но вы делаете inner join и заведомо отсекаете курсы, на которых нет студентов и при этом хотите увидеть count == 0. Ну так не бывает. Это как из корзины разноцветных яблок выбрать зелёные и удивляться почему же нет красных. Ну потому что вы так выбрали. Разве нет?

Comment: @ArchDemon все верно, я надеялся, что есть возможность сделать какое-то условие else для пустых курсов. Подскажите, как делают запрос в таких случаях, не отсекая пустые курсы?

Comment: Мне сколько раз нужно написать про `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon, но если сделать left join, то count выдаст 1, а не 0. Хотя, наверное в count можно загнать поверку, что там не null.

Comment: @ArchDemon вы оказались правы, я из-за невнимательности смотрел не на тот результат и казалось, что работает одинаково. Спасибо!